# What is the meaning of "potato mashers" and no wings?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

> "There were no wings or potato mashers" for quite a while after the Big Bang. Evolution added wings; people added potato mashers. Evolution and people are also both involved in adding meaning to the universe.

- What is the meaning of "potato mashers" and no wings in this paragraph?

From:
https://meaningness.com/no-meaning-from-big-bang

Comment: Hi Sivajini, please always mention the source of text you quote. Can you [edit] that in? Welcome to ELL!

Comment: These words and phrases use their standard meanings here.

Comment: Although marginal, I vote to keep this question open. The OP appears to have edited it to include a link to the quotation and it isn't asking for **spelling, meaning or pronunciation** IMHO more interpretation of the whole text. However the meaning appears to be obvious to me, it means what it says!

Answer (score 3):

They have their everyday meanings:

'Wings' are wings on animals, and they have evolved over millions of years.

'potato mashers' are devices for mashing potatoes, and they first appeared at the moment the first human made one.

Comment: For example https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1LoCAhIUrBKNjSZPxq6x00pXaC/Double-mashed-potato-masher-device-pumpkin-mud-crushed-fruit-plate-for-gadgets-Kitchen-potato-ricer.jpg

Comment: Thanks, but that des not alter the answer. The words in that quote are used in their everyday senses.

Comment: It could just as easily been 'teaspoons' 'carpets', or 'frying pans' which are also familiar household items (things) - and the point is - are made by people.